# In Eslint, how to extend one single rule and not override it totally?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

I just wanted to extend a rule (not to override it totally) from a parent `.eslintrc.json` to the sub directory `app/.eslintrc.json` file.

This is my parent `.eslintrc.json` file:

```json
{
  ...

  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "rules": {
        "@my-rule-name": [
          "error",
          {
            "param0": "value0",
            "param1": "value1",
            "paramArray": [
              { "a": 0 }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my sub directory `app/.eslintrc.json` file:

```json
{
  ...

  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "extends": ["../.eslintrc.json"],
      "rules": {
        "@my-rule-name": [
          "error",
          {
            "param2": "value2",
            "paramArray": [
              { "b": 1 }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For the child file, I actually like to keep `param0`, `param1`, and `paramArray` from the parent, and just add `param2` and more items to the `paramArray`. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for any help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't believe this is possible. Most rules are just on or off, some have one or two parameters to configure. Because of that I can't see there being a typical use case for extending a rule config being baked into eslint

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to share configuration like this between configs using standard ESLint tooling.

You will need to build some utilities to help you share it, if you want to go this route.

Often times people will resort to a pattern like

```
// parent
export const oneSpecificRuleConfig = { 
  "param0": "value0",
  "param1": "value1",
  "paramArray": [
    { "a": 0 }
  ]
};
export default {
  // ...
  "@my-rule-name": ["error", oneSpecificRuleConfig],
};

// child config
import { onsSpecificRuleConfig } from 'parent_config';

export default {
  // ...
  "@my-rule-name": ["error", {
    ...oneSpecificRuleConfig,
    "param2": "value2",
    "paramArray": [
      { "b": 1 }
    ]
  }],
};
```